# Multithread management in view?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 3 button and 3 textview.When i press first button i want to see 10 sec later which is writing in the first textview.i press second button i want to see someting 5 sec later which is writing in the second textview .i press third button,i want to see textview which is writing  immediately.

My question how can i work all multithread in the view without lock other view? I tried ASCYNTask but it doestn work.

Can anybody give me any suggestion?

My Activity:

```
 package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    Button a,b,c;
    TextView ta,tb,tc;
    Ascyn ascyn,ascyn2,ascyn3;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        a=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ba);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bb);
        c=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bc);
        ta=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ta);
        tb=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tb);
        tc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tc);


        ascyn=new Ascyn(this);
        ascyn2=new Ascyn(this);
        ascyn3=new Ascyn(this);
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               ascyn.execute();
                SystemClock.sleep(5000);
                ta.setText("ok");


            }
        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ascyn2.execute();
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                tb.setText("ozaman");
            }
        });

        c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ascyn3.execute();

                tc.setText("byby");}
        });

    }
}





  Ascyn:





 package com.example;

        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;

        /**
         * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
         * User: duygukahraman
         * Date: 20.02.2012
         * Time: 15:44
         * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
         */
        public class Ascyn extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void> {
            private Context ctx;
            ProgressDialog dialog;

            public Ascyn(Context context){
                ctx=context;
                dialog=new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
             //   dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
             //   dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

               // SystemClock.sleep(20000);
                return (null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Handler. Next suggestion: Show us how you tried it with a AsyncTask.

Comment: @WarrenFaith.I added my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to create separate Async class for each thread like.

 public class AscynThread1 extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void> { // }

 public class AscynThread2 extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void> { // }

 public class AscynThread3 extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void> { // }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need threads, if you simply want to write some text in a textview. Use a handler instead.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void method() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            textView.setText("Your text");
        }
    }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: What is different handler and thread?I think handler working with thread?